# SQL Server to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I need to create a trigger in SQL Server.

Trigger works:

If I found new line where T = 'A'; then add this line to PostgreSQL table.

Is it possible to create it, without software?

(I know how to create trigger, but how to create connection between two servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to setup postgres as a linked server to SQL server.

See [this](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/index.php?/archives/46-Setting-up-PostgreSQL-as-a-Linked-Server-in-Microsoft-SQL-Server-64-bit.html) article to see how to do so.